# How to disable sorting JQuery DataTable with asp.net Gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sorting, gridview, datatables

I have a Datatable, at run time it will create and bind to `Gridview Control`, So I dnt know how many columns it would be,
Now i want to allow sorting only for 2nd Columns .i.e `Name` rest all will be disable.

```
 $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1').dataTable({
     "bJQueryUI": true,
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     // "aoColumns": [{ "bSortable": false }, null]
 });
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h8RH7/32/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting problem. The datatables forum has a discussion very closely related to the issue you are encountering.

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11967/aocolumns-when-number-of-columns-vary/p1

Allan Jardine, creator of datatables, is part of the discussion, and his first reply recommended using `aoColumnDefs` and showed how you could do `aTargets: [ '_all' ]`
to take care of the issue of variable number of columns.

So based on a quick scan of the discussion on the datatables forum, 
here's a fiddle that might get you close to what you are looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/nLYLv/

```
 $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1').dataTable({
     "bJQueryUI": true,
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
         "aoColumnDefs": [
            {"aTargets": [ 1 ], "bSortable": true },
            {"aTargets": [ '_all' ], "bSortable": false }  
        ], 
       // force the arrow to show on 2nd column
       "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']]
 });
```